# Como crear un formulario en el que el usuario que lo rellene pueda añadir más campos según su necesidad

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web, formularios

Por ejemplo tengo este formulario que para registrar y en el campo de idiomas me gustaria tener la opcion de añadir más.

```
<form>

            <h1>Registro Personal</h1>
            <p>
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "nombre" name = "nombre">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Apellidos</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "apellidos" name = "apellidos" >
            </p>
            <p> Idiomas
                <label for = idioma >Idiomas</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "idioma" name = "idioma">

                <label for = nivel >Nivel</label>
                 <select name="nivel" id="area">
                    <option value="0">Bajo</option>
                    <option value="1">Intermedio</option>
                    <option value="2">Alto</option>
                 </select>
            </p>
           <button onclick="enviarDatos()">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que si una persona sabe varios idiomas que tenga la opcion (como un boton +) de añadir más idiomas?

Comment: Buen día, hay otra publicación con una [pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/329605/171630), por favor revísala, ya que parece ser que esta es un duplicado.

Comment: Gracias, no la había visto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como añadir más text field a un formulario a partir de un button?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329605/como-a%c3%b1adir-m%c3%a1s-text-field-a-un-formulario-a-partir-de-un-button)

Comment: Más o menos, lo que pasa es que me gustaría añadir a la vez el input text y el select, y en ese ejemplo solo lo hace con el div. ¿Se pueden añadir varios?

Comment: Puedes utilizar el método `appendChild()` y agregar los elementos que necesites

Comment: Vale, seria en vez de el div.textContent="Esta es una nueva nota creada con js", crearía por ejemplo el input y el select y haria el div.appendChild() de cada uno de ellos, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podria ser algo como esto:

```
<form>
 <form>
            <h1>Registro Personal</h1>
            <p>
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "nombre" name = "nombre">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Apellidos</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "apellidos" name = "apellidos" >
            </p>
            <p> Idiomas
                <label for = idioma >Idiomas</label>
                <input type = "text" id = "idioma" name = "idioma">

                <label for = nivel >Nivel</label>
                 <select name="nivel" id="area">
                    <option value="0">Bajo</option>
                    <option value="1">Intermedio</option>
                    <option value="2">Alto</option>
                 </select>

//AGREGAS EL BOTON PARA MAS IDIOMAS
<input type = "button" id = "otro-idioma" name = "otro-idioma" value="Agregar idioma">
            </p>

           <button onclick="enviarDatos()">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

luego el script para la accion:

```
const $otroIdioma = document.getElementById('otro-idioma')
       $otroIdioma.addEventListener('click', () => {
        $otroIdioma.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<p>Otro idioma:
                 <label for = idioma >Idiomas</label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "idioma" name = "idioma">
 
                 <label for = nivel >Nivel</label>
                  <select name="nivel" id="area">
                     <option value="0">Bajo</option>
                     <option value="1">Intermedio</option>
                     <option value="2">Alto</option>
                  </select>
               
             </p>`)
       })
```

Se asigna el boton nuevo a una constante, luego se le agrega el listener del click, cuando se dispara mediante la funcion insertAdjacentHTML le indico que agregue un nuevo formulario de idioma justo debajo del boton. Si sigues presionando sigue agregando idiomas, espero te sirva

EDITADO:

Tal vez no sea la solucion mas elegante pero funciona. Con ese simple agregado te genera name y id diferentes:

```
const $otroIdioma = document.getElementById('otro-idioma')
 let contIdioma = 1;
       $otroIdioma.addEventListener('click', () => {
        $otroIdioma.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<p>Otro idioma:
                 <label for = idioma >Idiomas</label>
                 <input type = "text" id="idioma-${contIdioma}"name = "idioma-${contIdioma}">
 
                 <label for = nivel >Nivel</label>
                  <select name="nivel-${contIdioma}" id="area-${contIdioma}">
                     <option value="0">Bajo</option>
                     <option value="1">Intermedio</option>
                     <option value="2">Alto</option>
                  </select>
               
             </p>`)
             contIdioma++;
       })
```

Comment: Hola, si es justo lo que quería. Muchas gracias, te lo agradezco!

Comment: ¿No pasa nada si los ids se repiten?

Comment: No tube en cuenta lo de los ids. Que funcion cumplen?

Comment: Los guardo en una variable para obtener los datos del formulario

Comment: Puedes ovbiar los ids y hacer un   a seleccion por attributo nombre e iterar a traves de ellos e ir guardando los datos en un objeto para luego trabajarlos. Si es que necesitas los ids habria q ver la forma de agregarlos dinamicamente con diferencia ej idioma1, idioma2 etc

Comment: Sobre los ids https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233191/repeated-ids-in-an-html-document-how-bad-an-idea-is-it-if-they-are-scoped-by